# import { Swiper } from './swiper.js' problem in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, es6-modules, swiper.js

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Hpg.png)

hi i am having this problem while testing on next js with built in swiper,

import { Swiper } from './swiper.js';
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

the versions i am using are

"next": "^12.3.0",
"swiper": "^8.4.5",
"jest": "^29.0.2",

jest.config.js

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './'
});

const customJestConfig = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle module aliases (this will be automatically configured for you soon)
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@/public/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/public/$1'
  },

  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js', './src/__mocks__/mocks.ts'],
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!./src/**/_*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!**/*.d.ts',
    '!**/node_modules/**'
  ],

  coverageThreshold: {
    // global: {
    //   branches: 80,
    //   functions: 80,
    //   lines: 80,
    //   statements: 80,
    // },
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom'
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

this is the implementation of the component

```
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Virtual } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

SwiperCore?.use([Virtual, Navigation, Pagination]);

export const GallerySlider = () => {
  const [slides] = useState(
    Array.from({ length: 500 }).map((_, index) => `Slide ${index + 1}`)
  );

  return (
    <Box width={'100%'} height={'50vh'}>
      <Typography
        variant={'h2'}
        textAlign={'center'}
        marginBottom={{ xs: '2rem', md: '4rem' }}
      >
        Galeria
      </Typography>
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={3}
        centeredSlides={true}
        spaceBetween={30}
        pagination={{ type: 'fraction' }}
        navigation={true}
        virtual
      >
        {slides.map((slideContent, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={slideContent} virtualIndex={index}>
            {slideContent}
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

If anyone can give me a hand with this error I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

the solution  that did it for  me was downgrading to swiper@6.8.0

Comment: Yes but I don't like that option, there should be some way to use the latest version, for now I deactivated it because I tried several things and they didn't work for me but I would like to fix it.